# Perturbation Method [formulation]

Tags: perturbation-theory

Recently when I am reading about perturbation method from following book:
**Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science**; 
I came out with following formulation:
$S_n = \sum_{0\leq k\leq n}a_k$

Then we rewrite $S_{n+1}$ in two ways, by splitting off both its last term and its first term:
$S_n + a_{n+1} = \sum_{0\leq k\leq n+1}a_k = a_0 + \sum_{1\leq k\leq n+1}a_k$

= $a_0 + \sum_{1\leq k+1\leq n+1}a_{k+1}$ **[What is the logic behind this part of transformation, suddenly change the k to k+1 without any change in the range?]**

= $a_0 + \sum_{0\leq k\leq n}a_{k+1}$
Can anyone explain that part I have mentioned here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine. By introducing
\begin{equation}
j = k-1,
\end{equation}
we can write
\begin{equation}
a_k = a_{j+1},
\end{equation}
and the domain $1\leq k \leq n+1$ corresponds to $0 \leq j \leq n$,
which is equivalent to $1 \leq j+1 \leq n+1$.
Hence 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n+1} a_k = \sum_{1 \leq j+1 \leq n+1} a_{j+1}.
\end{equation}
Now you can write the dummy index $j$ on the right hand side as $k$.

Well, in any way, the step of the question looks not necessary, and one can jump straight to the last line in your question.